# How to determine voltage level of the ultrasonic transducer?

Tags: voltage, design, high-voltage, output, transducer

I am designing the generator for an  ultrasonic transducer for a cleaning system and I am not sure how to set the output voltage level.

I measured the voltage level of the existing products, peak voltage was around 150V ~ 200V.

When I searched for information about the ultrasonic transducer, there is no specific output voltage level. It does not show output voltage like this.

[image]

What I'm confused about now is this:

1. If the output power of the 20kHz transducer is 100W, does that mean the output power at the resonance frequency of 20kHz?
2. If 1. is right, then if the impedance of the transducer is 25ohm at resonance, the output voltage should be 50V (from P=V^2/R.)

In fact, 50V is too small for what I'm used to seeing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output power to drive voltage equation, you are not allowing for the conversion efficiency of the transducer.  A quick review of the literature suggests conversion efficiencies of 20-40%, with the normal for typical systems being at the lower end of the range.

Thus if you are seeking 100W of ultrasonic power, you should expect to put in around 300-500W, and given a 25R load this equates to around 85V-115V RMS drive.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that efficiency, thanks for the advice!